# limit of a Wolstenholme sequence

Tags: real-analysis

let $s\in \mathbb{R}$.
How to calculate the  limit

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \left(\dfrac in\right)^{sn}$$

Comment: @aziiri Not the same limit, but close. Look at the exponent.

Comment: @DonThousand: My bad, sorry .

Comment: @aziiri No problem! I was simply letting you know.

Comment: thanks.Not the same exponent but the same result I think.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the sum as

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{i}{n}\right)^{sn} =1+ \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \left(\frac{n-i}{n}\right)^{sn}=1+ \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \left(1-\frac{i}{n}\right)^{sn}$$ 
Notice that $\left(1-\frac{i}{n}\right)^{sn}= e^{-is}+ \mathcal{O}\left(e^{-i s}i^2n^{-1}\right)$. By taking the sum of all terms and taking the limit you'd find that 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{i}{n}\right)^{sn}= 1+\frac{1}{e^s-1}= \frac{e^s}{e^s-1}$$

Comment: thanks. but I can not see how:$ \sum_{i=1}^{n} \mathcal{O}\left(e^{-i s}i^2n^{-1}\right) \to 0$ when $n \to +\infty  $.

Comment: Notice that $\sum_{i=1}^ne^{-i s}i^2 \le \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} e^{-i s}i^2=C$ (the series converge. Therefore, $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \mathcal{O}\left(e^{-i s}i^2n^{-1}\right) =\mathcal{O}(n^{-1})$

Comment: thanks. But : $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \mathcal{O}\left(e^{-i s}i^2n^{-1}\right) =\mathcal{O}(n^{-1})$ is not precise : $\mathcal{O}(n^{-1}) $ depends on n..

Comment: @samad: How is that a problem?

Comment: we must write $O(n^{-1})= n^{-1}.A_{n}$ and prove that $A_{n} \to 0$ when $n \to \infty$

Comment: Not necessarily, $f(n)=n^{-1}$ means that there is $C>0$ such that $|f(n)|<Cn^{-1}$ for large enough $n$. The definition that you have mentioned is the definition of $o(n)$.